# Universal Image Loader image cache not working

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

I've been working on this code about caching image using Universal Image Loader. But it doesn't appear to be successful as the image still being loaded from the server, not from the cache as it should be. Here's the code that I've used. I hope somebody could point out where my mistake is. Thank You.

```
    public void setEventImage(String myImageVersion,String myImage){
    ImageEvent imgEvent = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    String imgUrl = "url of the image"
    String imgEventWidth = "";
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    DisplayImageOptions displayImageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .build();
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(displayImageOptions)
            .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(getApplicationContext(),60*1000,60*1000))
            .diskCache(new UnlimitedDiskCache(getCacheDir()))
            .writeDebugLogs()
            .build();
    imageLoader.init(config);
    imageLoader.loadImage(imgUrl, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            int width = loadedImage.getWidth();
            int height = loadedImage.getHeight();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            imgEventWidth = imgEvent.getWidth();
            double forivheight = (imgEventWidth * height) / width;
            int finalHeight = (int) Math.round(forivheight);

            imgEvent.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(loadedImage, width, finalHeight, false));
            imgEvent.setLayoutParams(imageViewParams);
        }
    });
}
```

and below is the log from the debug. There is line where it tells that the image was loaded from network, not cache.

```
11-27 08:44:46.772 28037-28037/com.example.me W/ImageLoader: Try to initialize ImageLoader which had already been initialized before. To re-init ImageLoader with new configuration call ImageLoader.destroy() at first.
11-27 08:44:46.782 28037-29220/com.example.me D/ImageLoader: Start display image task [http://mydomain/image/event/1.jpg?version=17_480x854]
11-27 08:44:46.782 28037-29220/com.example.me D/ImageLoader: Load image from network [http://mydomain/image/event/1.jpg?version=17_480x854]
11-27 08:44:46.852 28037-28037/com.example.me I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_register_buffer, handle:0x559be660, size:0x190500, fd:60
11-27 08:44:46.952 28037-28037/com.example.me I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_register_buffer, handle:0x557b4d38, size:0x190500, fd:71
11-27 08:44:46.982 28037-28037/com.example.me I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_unregister_buffer, handle:0x55c40730, size:0x190500, fd:63
11-27 08:44:46.982 28037-28037/com.example.me I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_unregister_buffer, handle:0x54c0c7f0, size:0x190500, fd:68
11-27 08:44:46.982 28037-28037/com.example.me I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_unregister_buffer, handle:0x50906a58, size:0x190500, fd:48
11-27 08:44:46.982 28037-28037/com.example.me I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_unregister_buffer, handle:0x55bc2058, size:0x190500, fd:54
11-27 08:44:48.023 28037-28037/com.example.me I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_register_buffer, handle:0x54c0ca30, size:0x190500, fd:48
11-27 08:44:48.053 28037-28037/com.example.me I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_register_buffer, handle:0x54c05670, size:0x190500, fd:53
11-27 08:44:48.463 28037-29220/com.example.me D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 195K, 4% free 20235K/20876K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
11-27 08:44:48.463 28037-29220/com.example.me I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 27.666MB for 7990288-byte allocation
11-27 08:44:48.483 28037-28046/com.example.me D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 28036K/28680K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
11-27 08:44:49.354 28037-28037/com.example.me D/ImageLoader: Display image in ImageAware (loaded from NETWORK) [http://mydomain/image/event/1.jpg?version=17_480x854]
11-27 08:44:49.384 28037-28037/com.example.me D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 66K, 3% free 27982K/28680K, paused 29ms, total 30ms
11-27 08:44:49.384 28037-28037/com.example.me I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 30.300MB for 2820112-byte allocation
11-27 08:44:49.414 28037-28046/com.example.me D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 30736K/31436K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
```

**Update**

The problem is because I set the image using loadedImage Bitmap:

```
imgEvent.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(loadedImage, width, finalHeight, false));
```

I removed above line and replaced that with code below:

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imgUrl, imgEvent, displayImageOptions);
```

Although both codes are from universal image loader, it appears that this is how we should do it so we can cache image.

Comment: What do mean exactly with "it does not appear to be successful"? Thanks.

Comment: Please describe your problem.

Comment: "it doesn't appear to be successful" is not helpful as being the sole input for diagnostics.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean the image still takes too much time to load. It looks like the image still loaded from the server, not from SD card as it should be. Thank you.

Comment: you need to set log level to debug on `Universal Image Loader` then you will see each image URL loaded, and a log says where it was loaded from i saw logs like loaded from (`Network` OR `Disk-Cache` OR `Mem-Cache`) so in this case you will findout what is going on, because `slow` or `take too long` should not mean it's not working...

Comment: I have set the log level, and as it shows at the debug log I've just post above, the image is still loaded from network.

Comment: I've found the answer. The problem is because I set the image from "loadedImage" bitmap from loadImage() method instead of using displayImage() method, although both are universal image loader's. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add below one ?

```
.resetViewBeforeLoading(false)
```

Your DisplayImageOptions should looks like below:

```
 DisplayImageOptions displayImageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(false)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .build();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, actually the problem is because I loaded the image using "loadedImage" bitmap provided by loadImage() method instead of displayImage() method as I mention at my updated post above.